# java - jQuery.toggle не работает после ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Есть такой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('#uf').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
    $('#pay').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
    $(document).on('change', '[data-toggle="toggle"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();

        $('#uf, #pay').css('color', function(index, value){
            if(value === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'){
                return 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
            }else{
                return 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
table { 
margin:50px auto;
}
th { 
background: white; 
color: black; 
font-weight: bold; 
text-align: center;
padding: 10px; 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
font-size: 18px;
}

td { 
padding: 10px; 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
text-align: left; 
font-size: 18px;
}
.labels tr td {
background-color: white;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.label tr td label {
display: block;
}
[data-toggle="toggle"] {
display: none;
}

.sum{
  text-align: center;
}

.details{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Объект</th>
<th id='uf'>Подобъект</th>
<th id='pay'>Платёж</th>
<th>Сумма</th>
<th>Детали</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody class="labels">
<tr>
<td>Чаплина</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>5000</td>
  <td class='details'>
<label for="чаплина">Показать</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="чаплина" data-toggle="toggle" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="hide">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Гараж</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>3000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>ЗОО</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>2000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tbody class="labels">
<tr>
<td>Энергетиков</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>5000</td>
  <td class='details'>
<label for="энергетиков">Показать</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="энергетиков" id="энергетиков" data-toggle="toggle">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="hide">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Гараж</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>3000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>ЗОО</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>2000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

После Ajax запроса не срабатывает `toggle()`. Если поставить туда `removeClass('hide')`, тогда отрабатывает. Как починить?
Ниже ajax, который возвращает таблицу:

```
function showPaysMonths(facility) {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    var search = ({"facility" : facility});

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url : "goPays",
        data : JSON.stringify(search),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            show(data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            show(e);
        }
    });
}
function show(data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    $('#cash-details').html(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понял почему так, но исправил следующим образом:
Изменил название класса с `hide` на `hideShow`. В CSS добавил:

```
.hideShow{
  display: none;
}
```

Итоговый вариант ниже:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hideShow').hide();
    $('#uf').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
    $('#pay').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
    $(document).on('change', '[data-toggle="toggle"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents().next('.hideShow').toggle();

        $('#uf, #pay').css('color', function(index, value){
            if(value === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'){
                return 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
            }else{
                return 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
th {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 18px;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.labels tr td {
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.label tr td label {
    display: block;
}
[data-toggle="toggle"] {
    display: none;
}

.hideShow{
    display: none;
}

.sum{
    text-align: center;
}

.details{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Объект</th>
<th id='uf'>Подобъект</th>
<th id='pay'>Платёж</th>
<th>Сумма</th>
<th>Детали</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody class="labels">
<tr>
<td>Чаплина</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>5000</td>
  <td class='details'>
<label for="чаплина">Показать</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="чаплина" data-toggle="toggle" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="hideShow">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Гараж</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>3000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>ЗОО</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>2000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tbody class="labels">
<tr>
<td>Энергетиков</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>5000</td>
  <td class='details'>
<label for="энергетиков">Показать</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="энергетиков" id="энергетиков" data-toggle="toggle">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="hideShow">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Гараж</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>3000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>ЗОО</td>
<td></td>
<td class='sum'>2000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```